# CYGNUS_MONGO_DATA_EXPIRATION doesn't work?

Tags: mongodb, fiware, fiware-orion, fiware-cygnus, fiware-sth-comet

I installed Orion, MongoDB, Cygnus and sth-comet with docker-compose. I set `CYGNUS_MONGO_DATA_EXPIRATION=60` for Cygnus.

I created a subscription to an Orion entity, but the historical data doesn't expire. I want the old data gone.

dockyer-compose.yaml is as follows:

```
version: "3.5"

services:
  # Databases - Orion uses Mongo-DB, Cygnus is persisting to Postgres
  # Modified to use password authentication between mongoDB and Fiware Orion to improve security in docker.
  mongo-db:
    image: mongo:4.4
    hostname: mongo-db
    container_name: mongo-db
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    #command: --nojournalS
    environment:
      - "MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=${MONGOUSERNAME}" # Define the mongoDB user name
      - "MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=${MONGOPASSWORD}" # Define passwords for security measures within docker
      - "MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=admin"
    volumes:
      - ./db:/data/db
      - ./configdb:/data/configdb

  orion:
    image: fiware/orion:3.3.1
    hostname: orion
    container_name: fiware-orion
    depends_on:
      - mongo-db
    environment:
      - "ORION_MONGO_HOST=mongo-db:27017"
      - "ORION_MONGO_USER=${MONGOUSERNAME}" # Define the mongoDB user name
      - "ORION_MONGO_PASSWORD=${MONGOPASSWORD}" # Define passwords for security measures within docker
      - "ORION_MONGO_AUTH_SOURCE=admin"
      - "ORION_PORT=1026"
      - "ORION_LOG_LEVEL=INFO"
    ports:
      - "1026:1026"
    command: -dbhost mongo-db
    networks:
      #- proxynet #Comment out the openwhisk network as it is not necessary when building the development server.
      - default

  # Cygnus is configured to write context data to PostgeSQL
  cygnus:
    image: fiware/cygnus-ngsi:2.14.0
    hostname: cygnus
    container_name: fiware-cygnus
    networks:
      - default
    depends_on:
      - mongo-db
    ports:
      - "5055:5055"
      - "5080:5080"
    environment:
      - "CYGNUS_MONGO_HOSTS=mongo-db:27017" # Hostname of the PostgreSQL server used to persist historical context data
      - "CYGNUS_MONGO_USER=${MONGOUSERNAME}"
      - "CYGNUS_MONGO_PASS=${MONGOPASSWORD}"
      - "CYGNUS_MONGO_AUTH_SOURCE=admin"
      - "CYGNUS_MONGO_SERVICE_PORT=5055"
      - "CYGNUS_LOG_LEVEL=DEBUG"
      - "CYGNUS_SERVICE_PORT=5055" # Notification Port that Cygnus listens to for Postgres subscriptions
      - "CYGNUS_API_PORT=5080" # Port that Cygnus listens on for operational reasons
      - "CYGNUS_ORION_SSL=true"
      - "CYGNUS_ORION_HOST=orion"
      - "CYGNUS_ORION_PORT=1026"
      - "CYGNUS_MONGO_DATA_EXPIRATION=60"

  sth-comet:
    image: fiware/sth-comet
    hostname: sth-comet
    container_name: fiware-sth-comet
    depends_on:
        - mongo-db
    networks:
      - default
    ports:
        - "8666:8666"
    environment:
        - "STH_HOST=0.0.0.0"
        - "STH_PORT=8666"
        - "DB_PREFIX=sth_"
        - "DB_USERNAME=${MONGOUSERNAME}"
        - "DB_PASSWORD=${MONGOPASSWORD}"
        - "DB_AUTH_SOURCE=admin"
        - "DB_URI=mongo-db:27017"
        - "LOGOPS_LEVEL=DEBUG"

volumes:
  mongo-db: ~

networks:
  default:
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 172.18.1.0/24
```

Prior to `docker-compose up -d`, I made the following directories:

- db
- config

Next, I set a subscription like this:

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:1026/v2/subscriptions -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d @- <<EOF
{
  "description": "Notify all context changes to Cygnus",
  "subject": {
    "entities": [
      {
        "idPattern": ".*"
      }
    ]
  },
  "notification": {
    "http": {
      "url": "http://cygnus:5055/notify"
    }
  }
}
EOF
```

The oriong's log is:

```
time=2021-12-14T00:32:01.654Z | lvl=INFO | corr=4130a13c-5c75-11ec-b540-0242ac120103 | trans=1639441850-794-00000000001 | from=172.18.1.1 | srv=<none> | subsrv=<none> | comp=Orion | op=logTracing.cpp[148]:logInfoRequestWithPayload | msg=Request received: POST /v2/subscriptions, request payload (217 bytes): {  "description": "Notify all context changes to Cygnus",  "subject": {    "entities": [      {        "idPattern": ".*"      }    ]  },  "notification": {    "http": {      "url": "http://cygnus:5055/notify"    }  }}, response code: 201
```

Then, I inserted the following entity:

```
curl localhost:1026/v2/entities -s -S -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d @- <<EOF
{"id":"Room1","type":"Room","temperature":{"value":23,"type":"Float"},"pressure":{"value":720,"type":"Integer"}}
EOF
```

Orion said(I'm sorry that I lost the head of the log line):

```
subsrv=<none> | comp=Orion | op=logTracing.cpp[148]:logInfoRequestWithPayload | msg=Request received: POST /v2/entities, request payload (112 bytes): {"id":"Room1","type":"Room","temperature":{"value":23,"type":"Float"},"pressure":{"value":720,"type":"Integer"}}, response code: 201
```

Then, I updated the entity:

```
curl localhost:1026/v2/entities/Room1/attrs -s -S -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -X PATCH -d @- <<EOF
{"temperature":{"value":24,"type":"Float"},"pressure":{"value":730,"type":"Float"}}
EOF
```

Orion said:

```
time=2021-12-14T00:37:12.558Z | lvl=INFO | corr=fa8479ba-5c75-11ec-8b92-0242ac120103 | trans=1639441850-794-00000000007 | from=172.18.1.1 | srv=<none> | subsrv=<none> | comp=Orion | op=logTracing.cpp[148]:logInfoRequestWithPayload | msg=Request received: PATCH /v2/entities/Room1/attrs, request payload (83 bytes): {"temperature":{"value":24,"type":"Float"},"pressure":{"value":730,"type":"Float"}}, response code: 204
time=2021-12-14T00:37:12.591Z | lvl=INFO | corr=fa8479ba-5c75-11ec-8b92-0242ac120103; cbnotif=1 | trans=1639441850-794-00000000008 | from=172.18.1.1 | srv=<none> | subsrv=/ | comp=Orion | op=logTracing.cpp[65]:logInfoHttpNotification | msg=Notif delivered (subId: 61b7e60138b3ce79144d71ab): POST cygnus:5055/notify, response code: 200
```

I waited some minutes and updated the entity again:

```
curl localhost:1026/v2/entities/Room1/attrs -s -S -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -X PATCH -d @- <<EOF
{"temperature":{"value":25,"type":"Float"},"pressure":{"value":740,"type":"Float"}}
EOF
```

The log of orion is:

```
time=2021-12-14T00:40:15.524Z | lvl=INFO | corr=6793036e-5c76-11ec-8fa2-0242ac120103 | trans=1639441850-794-00000000009 | from=172.18.1.1 | srv=<none> | subsrv=<none> | comp=Orion | op=logTracing.cpp[148]:logInfoRequestWithPayload | msg=Request received: PATCH /v2/entities/Room1/attrs, request payload (83 bytes): {"temperature":{"value":25,"type":"Float"},"pressure":{"value":740,"type":"Float"}}, response code: 204
time=2021-12-14T00:40:15.558Z | lvl=INFO | corr=6793036e-5c76-11ec-8fa2-0242ac120103; cbnotif=1 | trans=1639441850-794-00000000010 | from=172.18.1.1 | srv=<none> | subsrv=/ | comp=Orion | op=logTracing.cpp[65]:logInfoHttpNotification | msg=Notif delivered (subId: 61b7e60138b3ce79144d71ab): POST cygnus:5055/notify, response code: 200
```

Lastly, I printed out the historical data:[image: the historical data]

It shows the historical table contains the old updating. How can I eliminate the old ones automatically?

The log of cygnus is(It's so big that I made an excerpt of the log):
https://gist.github.com/ishidakei/b3aea7b287899c472b74a438ce4451c8

Comment: Since this appears to be a configuration rather than a programming issue, you would probably be better raising this over on the [Cygnus GitHub](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-cygnus/issues) - the subscription from Orion is valid and  firing, so it is merely something with the config.